# Vue-cli не выводится изображение в v-for

Tags: vue.js

Дорого времен суток, не могу разобраться с выводом изображений в цикле. использую vue-cli vuex

```
<img v-for="pic in pictures" :src="pic.src">


export default {
  data(){
   return {
    pictures:[ 
         {name: 'второй', src: '/assets/2.jpg'},
         {name: 'первый', src: '/assets/1.jpg'}
            ]
   }    
  } 
}
```

Пробовал прописывать `static` вместо `assets`

Использую шаблон webpack-simple

Comment: посмотрите, что в консоли пишет.

Comment: `http://localhost:8080/assets/2.jpg` 
Файл не найден.
Если прописываю вручную. не, то всё ок
<img src="../assets/.jpg" alt="">

Comment: ну так поставьте 2 точки в массиве картинок

Comment: К сожалению так не работает.

Comment: Не выводятся пути из переменных. Видимо нужны дополнительные настройки webpack

Answer (score 0):

Изменил путь до изображения в переменной с `../assets/pic.jpg` на `/dist/pic.jpg`

Теперь выводятся в цыкле.